# Inject component in textarea

Tags: reactjs

I need to generate a html text and then display it in a textarea to copy it easily.

Here's a simplified version of my code **([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-neumann-288tu?file=/src/App.js))**:

```js
function Text({ foo }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      {foo && <p>Foot</p>}
      <p>Baar</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onclick={() => {
          setToggle(!toggle);
        }}
      >
        Toogle!
      </button>
      <hr />
      <h2>Preview</h2>
      <Text foo={toggle} />
      <hr />
      <h2>HTML code :</h2>
      <textarea value={<Text foo={toggle} />} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The component return an [object Object]. How can I return the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)` to render the component's HTML to a string. You can also assign the component to a variable to ensure that the html value you populate the textarea with and the preview rendered in the return both reference the same instance of the component.

Documentation here: [ReactDOMServer](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html)

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactdomserver-to-render-element-to-string-xwwsi)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import "./styles.css";

function Text({ foo }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      {foo && <p>Foo</p>}
      <p>Baar</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);

  const element = <Text foo={toggle} />;
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element);

  console.log(element);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setToggle(!toggle);
        }}
      >
        Toogle!
      </button>
      <hr />

      <h2>Preview</h2>
        {element}
      <hr />

      <h2>HTML code :</h2>
      <textarea value={html} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you will be able to do that, since it is not HTML semantically correct. I tried to edit your CodeSendbox to put inside textarea dangerouslySetInnerHtml and it rendered message that it makes no sense rendering html elements inside textarea. What you can do is use some div instead of textarea and give it some css classes to make it look as textarea and place contenteditable as attribute on it, like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setToggle(!toggle);
        }}
      >
        Toogle!
      </button>
      <hr />

      <h2>Preview</h2>
      <Text foo={toggle} />
      <hr />

      <h2>HTML code :</h2>
      <div contentEditable className="divAsTextarea">
        <Text foo={toggle} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```